# Watch for element creation in greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, mutation-observers

I need to be notified when an element with class 'nav' is created as the document is loading. Googling I found MutationObservers and thought they would be perfect, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ii-shortcuts
// @namespace   https://github.com/RedHatter
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation)
    {
        if (mutation.target.getAttribute('class') == 'nav')
            GM_log('nav creation');
    });    
});
observer.observe(document, {subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['class']});
```

I also tried.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ii-shortcuts
// @namespace   https://github.com/RedHatter
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation)
    {
        if (mutation.addedNodes[0].getAttribute('class') == 'nav')
            GM_log('nav creation');
    });    
});
observer.observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

But in nether case was 'nav creation' log on page load. What am I missing?

Comment: @CrazyTrain Not accouding to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#syntax) "DOM mutation events must not fire for changes caused by the UA parsing the document ... However, mutation observers do fire, as required by the DOM specification."

Comment: you can use [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive), it provides nice simple api to listen for elements creation (uses MutationObserver internally)

Comment: Hmm ... look very nice. Thank you @UzairFarooq

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several issues (big to small):

1. When the document is first, statically loaded; the events are `childList` events, not `attributes` events.

   For example,

   ```
   $("body").append ('<p id="foo" class="bar">Hiya!</p><p>blah</p>');
   ```

   generates *one* `childList` event, while a subsequent

   ```
   $("#foo").attr ("class", "bar2");
   ```

   generates an `attributes` event.
2. The odds that `mutation.addedNodes[0]` contains an element with class `nav` are practically zero.  This is almost always a text node.
   You need to **check the whole array, PLUS the `target`.**
3. Don't use `getAttribute('class') == 'nav'` to check for classes.  This will throw exceptions for nodes without the `getAttribute` function and it will miss elements that have more than one class.  EG: `<p class="foo nav bar">...`

   Use `classList.contains()` on appropriate node types.
4. Use a `@grant` directive if you use any `GM_` functions like `GM_log()`.  Use a grant anyway, to ensure that the sandbox stays on.
5. Avoid the use of `// @include *`.  Especially with timers and observers, this can bog down your browser and your machine.
6. **This info is for Firefox.**  Chrome has big differences in how it implements Mutation observers.  This kind of code will not work in Chrome before page load.

---

Putting it all together, the script becomes:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _ii-shortcuts
// @namespace   https://github.com/RedHatter
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_log
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
var myObserver       = new MutationObserver (mutationHandler);
var obsConfig        = {
    childList: true, attributes: true,
    subtree: true,   attributeFilter: ['class']
};

myObserver.observe (document, obsConfig);

function mutationHandler (mutationRecords) {

    mutationRecords.forEach ( function (mutation) {

        if (    mutation.type               == "childList"
            &&  typeof mutation.addedNodes  == "object"
            &&  mutation.addedNodes.length
        ) {
            for (var J = 0, L = mutation.addedNodes.length;  J < L;  ++J) {
                checkForCSS_Class (mutation.addedNodes[J], "nav");
            }
        }
        else if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
            checkForCSS_Class (mutation.target, "nav");
        }
    } );
}

function checkForCSS_Class (node, className) {
    //-- Only process element nodes
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        if (node.classList.contains (className) ) {
            console.log (
                'New node with class "' + className + '" = ', node
            );
            // YOUR CODE HERE
            //GM_log ('nav creation');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! though I was going to add a `@grant` when the script was done (you get that annoying pop otherwise), and I only put `@include *` 'cause I didn't want to show what site I was using the script on.

Answer (score 0):

MutationObservers are called for more things than just adding nodes, including changes to attributes and removing nodes.

So watch out for `mutation.addedNodes` returning null - in which case this code will fail.  Try:

```
if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes[0].getAttribute('class') === 'nav') {
  ...
```

The mutation object also has a 'type' attribute that you can use to get more info; have you read the API docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)? There are some good examples there.

Comment: I tried the code, doesn't change anything. The problem isn't the script failing, it's that an element with class nav is never passed to the MutationObserver. And yes I have read the docs.

Comment: Do you have a test page with the HTML that you are watching with this code?

Comment: @Wheeyls Are you sure that the attribute is added to the node prior to it being placed into the tree? The observer might be called when the mutation is made instead of being batched for later, so if whatever is inserting nodes inserts the node prior to setting the class, that might be the issue.