# How to mobilize all links, in a browsed page, using Google Mobilizer?

Tags: firefox, mobile, web, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make the links on some of my pages "mobilized" with this great service by [Google Mobilizer](http://www.google.com/gwt/n).

EG: change URLs like:

```
http://imgur.com/
```

to:

```
http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=imgur.com
```

*Google Mobilizer* reduces the size of whatever URL is passed to it greatly. Images get reduced in size. Only the first frame of animated gifs are rendered, and basically any resource is heavily reduced in size. This decreases the download time greatly on low-bandwidth and high latency connections.

Could this be done in Firefox by an add-on or a userscript? So that all the links on a webpage are prefixed by `www.google.com/gwt/x?u=`?

There's [a Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-google-mobilizer/oboidcglhhomiockniojcalimciglkeb?hl=en) which actually gives you a context-menu item to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me. It replaces all links on a page with Google Mobilizer URL appended to them.

```
if (!(
// Except when on ...
            (/google.com\/search/.test(document.URL))
        ||  (/google.*\/gwt/.test(document.URL))
    )){     
    var link = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
        if (!(
//Only for external links
                    (link[i].hostname == window.location.hostname)
//And except for links that contain... 
                ||  (/google\./.test(link[i].href))
                ||  (/stack/.test(link[i].href))
                ||  (/reddit\./.test(link[i].href))
//And except for Null & Javascript-purpose links...
                ||  (/\0/.test(link[i].href))
            )){
//Mobilize all links (append mobilizer URL)
            link[i].href = link[i].href.replace("http","http://google.com/gwt/x?u=http")
            }
        }
    }
else if (/google.*\/gwt/.test(document.URL)){
// But when on Google Mobilizer site itself, ...
    var link = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")
    for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
        if ((/gwt\/x\/e\?/.test(link[i].href))) {
//De-mobilize (just) "View page directly" link (because it unnecessarily prompts for redirection)
            var inner = link[i].href.indexOf('http',1);
            inner = inner>-1 ? link[i].href.substr(inner,link[i].href.indexOf('&',inner)-inner) : false;
            if (inner)
                link[i].href = inner;
            }
        }
    }
```

It also checks to see `if` the links are of the parent site domain, and doesn't change them.

Comment: This just does *static* links, while your question talked, more than a little, about ***images*** and included imgur.com in it's example URL.  This approach also doesn't work on AJAX driven pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Firefox add-on can do this and a *Firefox* Greasemonkey script should also be able to do it.

Here's an outline of how it might be done with a *Firefox-only* Greasemonkey script:

1. Set the script to [run at `document-start` and use `MutationObserver`s to watch for the creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632475/331508) of new `<a>`, `<img>`, and *possibly* `<iframe>` elements.
2. When a new `<a>`, `<iframe>`, etc. element is found, rewrite its `src` or `href` property to use the mobilizer service.
3. When a new `<img>` is found things get a little trickier.  *I think* that if you delete the `<img>` node, it stops the load of that image (if it had already started).  This needs to be tested, as well as the effects on the image server.

   If the original image is still loaded, then abandon this approach and use an add-on. OR, you could use AdBlock Plus to block the original images.

   Anyway, the steps in this case would be:

   1. Copy the `<img>` node's `outerHTML`.
   2. Note the `<img>` node's parent and node position in relation to sibling nodes.
   3. Delete the `<img>` node.
   4. Modify the `src` part to point to the mobilizer service.
   5. Create a new `<img>` node, where the old one was.